# powershell tilde/Desktop after moving user data to another disk

Tags: powershell-3.0

My user account files have moved to it's own disk (i.e. D:\foo) and I used the recommended practice of moving the special directories like Desktop by using the Properties/Location feature in Windows Explorer. Now in powershell, it can't find ~/Desktop, ~/Document, etc.

I thought remapping tilde could work but I couldn't find how to do that and regardless, I'm not sure if that's the best practice.

Powershell Gurus, can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers. In hindsight, I wasn't clear that I meant this question to be in the context of an interactive setting such as when you're doing something like "cd ~/Desktop" or "cp ~/Desktop/foo.txt ." in a Powershell window. I think the answers that were received (thanks!) regarding the environment variables were more appropriate for Powershell scripts (i.e. foo.ps1).

In any case, I found the answer on this post and added the two liner to my startup script. Now "cd ~/Desktop" goes to D:\foo\Desktop

http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/31790-override-filesystem-providers-treatment-tilde.html

```
$provider = get-psprovider filesystem
$provider.Home = 'D:\foo'
```

Answer (score 1):

I like your answer, hlo, but i don't like polluting my profile with unnecessary variables. I cut it down to this one-liner for my profile:

```
(get-psprovider filesystem).Home = "C:\Users\fez"
```

Now if i could just figure out why `~` and `$HOME` don't resolve to the same location as `$env:home` and `%HOME%`

Comment: Are you running in an environment where your user profile folder is redirected to a different drive? If so, DON'T!!! See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 1):

By default, PowerShell is configured to resolve '~' to your user profile folder. Typically, this is 'c:\users\'.

However, if you're running on a machine or in an environment which has had its home/user-profile folder moved somewhere other than 'c:\users...', then PowerShell might not be able to find the user profile folder.

Moving your user-profile folder to a different location is likely to break MANY apps and, in fact, in Win8.1 has been seen to be the cause of numerous app crashes, system instability, etc. in addition to causing PowerShell to work incorrectly.

Ed Bott recently wrote-up newly updated official guidance from Microsoft on this issue:

**[Don't move your Windows user profiles folder to another drive](http://www.zdnet.com/dont-move-your-windows-user-profiles-folder-to-another-drive-7000022142/)**

You can tell PowerShell where it should look for your home folder using the answers given by Fez & HLO:

```
(get-psprovider filesystem).Home = "C:\Users\<user>"
```

You may need to add the command above to your default PowerShell User Profile so that you don't have to keep typing the above line:

```
C:\Users\<user>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

If you want to move the location of your docs, photos, etc., it'll probably make more sense to add the new folders' locations to the appropriate Libraries. That way. anything that needs to write to the root of your user-profile (e.g. Git, SSH, etc.) can do so while anything that needs to write a doc/photo/music file can be transparently redirected to the alternate location.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell will accept `~` for the user's home directory, but for reasons I don't recall it's not a good idea to use it.

The environment variables linked in the other answer here are available from PowerShell, but don't use the `%VARNAME%` syntax - that's batch. Use the `Env:` PSProvider - so the user home dierctory is `$Env:USERPROFILE` in PowerShell. You can see all currently-defined environment variables with `get-childitem env:`.